# How to sort recursive queries in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I wrote a query in this way, but I want to sort it in the way shown below.
However, the comments are not sorted and you cannot get the desired result.

```
create table tree_table
(
    id int not null, 
    parent_id int not null, 
    name nvarchar(30) not null 
);

insert into tree_table (id, parent_id, name) 
values
(1, 0, '1Title'),
(2, 0, '2Title'),
(3, 0, '3Title'),
(4, 1,  '  ㄴRE 1Title 1-1'),
(5, 1,  '  ㄴRE 1Title 1-2'),
(6, 1,  '  ㄴRE 1Title 1-3'),
(7, 2,  '  ㄴRE 2Title 1-1'),
(8, 2,  '  ㄴRE 2Title 1-2'),
(9, 2,  '  ㄴRE 2Title 1-3'),
(10, 4, '    ㄴRE 1Title 1-1-1'),
(11, 4, '    ㄴRE 1Title 1-1-2'),
(12, 4, '    ㄴRE 1Title 1-1-3'),
(13, 3, '  ㄴRE 3Title 1-1'),
(14, 1, '  ㄴRE 1Title 1-4'),
(15, 6, '    ㄴRE 3Title 1-3-1'),
(16, 0, '4Title'),
(17, 16, '  ㄴRE 4Title 1-1'),
(18, 15, '      ㄴRE 3Title 1-3-1-1'),
(19, 16, '  ㄴRE 4Title 1-2'),
(20, 17, '    ㄴRE 4Title 1-1-1');
```

Select query:

```
WITH rcte AS
(
    SELECT 
        t.id AS 'thread',
        t.id,
        t.parent_id,
        t.name
    FROM
        tree_table t
    WHERE 
        t.parent_id = 0
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        r.thread,
        t.id,
        t.parent_id,
        t.name
    FROM
        tree_table t
    JOIN
        rcte r ON r.id = t.parent_id
),
sorted_threads AS
(
    SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY MAX(r.id) DESC) AS sort_number,
        r.thread
    FROM 
        rcte r
    GROUP BY 
        r.thread
)
SELECT
    st.sort_number,
    r.id,
    r.parent_id,
    r.name
FROM
    sorted_threads st
JOIN
    rcte r ON r.thread = st.thread
ORDER BY
    st.sort_number
```

Result - sorted by the above query:

```
sort_number id    parent_id    name
----------- ----  ----------   ----------------
1           16    0            4Title
1           17    16             ㄴRE 4Title 1-1
1           19    16             ㄴRE 4Title 1-2
1           20    17               ㄴRE 4Title 1-1-1
2           1     0            1Title
2           4     1              ㄴRE 1Title 1-1
2           5     1              ㄴRE 1Title 1-2
2           6     1              ㄴRE 1Title 1-3
2           10    4                ㄴRE 1Title 1-1-1
2           11    4                ㄴRE 1Title 1-1-2
2           12    4                ㄴRE 1Title 1-1-3
2           14    1              ㄴRE 1Title 1-4
2           15    6                ㄴRE 3Title 1-3-1
2           18    15    　　　        ㄴRE 3Title 1-3-1-1
3           3     0            3Title
3           13    3              ㄴRE 3Title 1-1
4           2     0            2Title
4           7     2              ㄴRE 2Title 1-1
4           8     2              ㄴRE 2Title 1-2
4           9     2              ㄴRE 2Title 1-3
```

I want to sort like this - when comment, that post should go to the top:

```
sort_number id    parent_id    name
----------- ----  ----------   ----------------
1           16    0            4Title
1           17    16             ㄴRE 4Title 1-1
1           20    17               ㄴRE 4Title 1-1-1
1           19    16             ㄴRE 4Title 1-2
2           1     0            1Title
2           14    1              ㄴRE 1Title 1-4
2           15    6                ㄴRE 3Title 1-3-1
2           18    15    　　　        ㄴRE 3Title 1-3-1-1
2           6     1              ㄴRE 1Title 1-3
2           10    4                ㄴRE 1Title 1-1-1
2           11    4                ㄴRE 1Title 1-1-2
2           12    4                ㄴRE 1Title 1-1-3
2           5     1              ㄴRE 1Title 1-2
2           4     1              ㄴRE 1Title 1-1
3           3     0            3Title
3           13    3              ㄴRE 3Title 1-1
4           2     0            2Title
4           9     2              ㄴRE 2Title 1-3
4           8     2              ㄴRE 2Title 1-2
4           7     2              ㄴRE 2Title 1-1
```

How do I change the query to reflect like the above result?

Thanks for your answer

Comment: Just saying you want the results in X order doesn't help.  What is the context that 4Title is first, then 1, then 3, then 2 with sub-items.  Can you please edit your post and clarify what the basis is for the sort. IMO, whichever comment entered last floats that entire tree segment to the top, then next comment tree.  Please confirm.

Comment: Please add the query you are currently using, and explain why it is not giving you the results you want.

Comment: @DRapp

The default sorting method is parent_id, and comments in parent_id should always be sorted in the latest order.
When the latest post is posted, it should be at the top.
If you are writing a newer post or commenting on an old post, you will be taken to the top
However, comments are not placed under parent_id.

Comment: @Nick
I have added my query. Please confirm.

Comment: How many levels of children can there be?

Comment: How `2           14    1              ㄴRE 1Title 1-4
2           15    6                ㄴRE 3Title 1-3-1` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build `varchar` sort key recursively and sort descending with a trick so that shorter values are considered greater.

```
WITH sorted AS
(
    SELECT 
        right(cast (1000000 + (select coalesce(max(t2.id),t.id) from tree_table t2 where t2.parent_id = t.id )as varchar(max)),6) AS [sort_key],
        t.id,
        t.parent_id,
        t.name
    FROM
        tree_table t
),
rcte AS (
    SELECT * 
    FROM  sorted t
    WHERE 
        t.parent_id = 0
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        r.sort_key + t.sort_key,
        t.id,
        t.parent_id,
        t.name
    FROM
        sorted t
    JOIN
        rcte r ON r.id = t.parent_id
)
SELECT * 
FROM rcte
ORDER BY 
   stuff(replicate(cast ('9' as varchar(max)), (select max(len(r2.sort_key)) from rcte r2)),1,len(sort_key), sort_key) 
DESC;
```

I assumed id <1000000 for simplicity, you can easily adjust it to any big value with `bigint` arithmetic.

Output :

```
sort_key                    id  parent_id   name
000019                      16  0   4Title
000019000020                17  16    ㄴRE 4Title 1-1
000019000020000020          20  17      ㄴRE 4Title 1-1-1
000019000019                19  16    ㄴRE 4Title 1-2
000014                      1   0   1Title
000014000015                6   1     ㄴRE 1Title 1-3
000014000015000018          15  6       ㄴRE 3Title 1-3-1
000014000015000018000018    18  15        ㄴRE 3Title 1-3-1-1
000014000014                14  1     ㄴRE 1Title 1-4
000014000012                4   1     ㄴRE 1Title 1-1
000014000012000012          12  4       ㄴRE 1Title 1-1-3
000014000012000011          11  4       ㄴRE 1Title 1-1-2
000014000012000010          10  4       ㄴRE 1Title 1-1-1
000014000005                5   1     ㄴRE 1Title 1-2
000013                      3   0   3Title
000013000013                13  3     ㄴRE 3Title 1-1
000009                      2   0   2Title
000009000009                9   2     ㄴRE 2Title 1-3
000009000008                8   2     ㄴRE 2Title 1-2
000009000007                7   2     ㄴRE 2Title 1-1
```

Comment: INSERT INTO tree_table (id, parent_id, name) VALUES (21, 9, '      ㄴRE 2Title 1-3-1');
Then result
2Title must go above 3Title.
But it is located under RE 2Title 1-3
What's the way to rearrange it?

Comment: @kudy, this task is different from the original one. If I've got it right, new query must find the latest message down all the subtree of the given node as  a sort key. Please create a separate question for that.